# Using self in class function defined outside of class

Tags: python, class

I'm working on a project where I have a class that accepts a function in its `__init__` like the following

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, func,param1,param2):
        self.function=func
        self.param1=param1
        self.param2=param2
    def doSomething(self):
        print("hi there")
```

Obviously, when creating an instance of this class, I would pass in a function to the constructor. However, what if, in that function, I wanted to refer to `doSomething` and `param1`. Could I access them, if my function is defined outside the class?

For example, suppose this is the function I'll pass to the constructor

```
def func(self):
    self.doSomething()
    return(self.param1)
```

If this function was in the class definition, this would obviously work. How can I make it work in this circumstance?

Comment: You can make them parameters to the function.

Comment: @Goyo However, that would mean anytime I'd seek to call the function, I'd have to refer to all of the parameters of the class, despite the function being in the class. Is there not a better way?

Comment: I suggest you try defining the function outside the class (the way shown) and see if it works...the results may surprise you.

Comment: @martineau I tried this 

    `Ex = Example(func,1,2);
    print(Ex.function())`. 

I got the error: TypeError: func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: It sounds like `func` is actually a method and not a standalone function.

Comment: @RushabhMehta You don't have to refer to `param2`. Anyway with names like `Example`, `doSomething`, `func`, `param1`... is not easy to tell what is better or worse.

Comment: @Goyo I rather not post my whole code, as a lot of it is irrelevant to my question. I tried to boil it down to the basic problem.

Comment: @erip elaborate please? I'm not sure I understand

Comment: I didn't ask you to post your whole code. Anyway @martineau is right, What makes you think the code you wrote won't work? Why don't you take the time to run it?

Comment: @Goyo I ran it, as I wrote in a previous comment. I got  TypeError: func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: Change your comment code to pass the object (Ex) as the parameter: `Ex = Example(func,1,2); print(Ex.function(Ex))`

Comment: @RushabhMehta That's weird, your code doesn't even call `func`.

Comment: @Anand I could do that, but I would prefer not to: I actually have a lot of functions.

Comment: @Goyo Right??? It's so confusing

Comment: Why not pass in the object? You must have the object since you just constructed it.

Comment: What's the use case for this? can you post a clear example instead of "dosmething", "param1", etc? whare would "func" be defined?

Comment: @arieljuod I have another class that has an array of objects instantiated using this class, I seek to call this function from all of the objects and aggregate their results. These functions require the use of the parameters in the class to aid them (This is for PPCG)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments it looks like this is what you want:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, func, param1, param2):
        self.function = lambda: func(self)
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2

    def doSomething(self):
        print("hi there")


def func(self):
    self.doSomething()
    return(self.param1)


example = Example(func, 1, 2)
example.function()
```

I feel like this is the wrong way to solve whatever problem you want to solve, though.

Comment: @RushabhMehta Well why shouldn't it? It's just plain old python. Also the meaningless names you chose make hard to explain the code. What's what you don't understand?

Comment: Oh I see, the lambda function. I didn't see that before. That makes a lot of sense now!